# How to play at time only one jwplayer in page while other players stop which are playing

Tags: php, jquery, jwplayer

How to stop all jwplayers in page. my goal is only one jwplayer play at time, container id is dynamic and unique.

> i want to like this.

`$('All_dynamic_player_container_ids').stop();$('dynamic_player_container_id').play();`

> Jwplayer code is bellow

```
<?php while(list($display_name, $iId, $uid, $caption, $dt, $post_type, $ext,$blocked_user,$special,$stream_id, $comments, $likes, $userLiked , $exclusive) = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{ ?>
    <div class="post_image video_image<?php echo $iId ?>" id="video_image<?php echo $iId ?>"></div>
    <?php 
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("video_image'.$iId.'").setup({
    sources: [{
    file: "../vids/user/'.$uid.'-'.$iId.'.mp4", 
    },],
    image:"../imgs/user/'.$uid.'-'.$iId.'.jpg",
    logo: {
    file: "../images/logo/melogo.png",
    link: "http://'.SERVER.'",
    hide:true
    },
    modes: [{
    type: "html5"
    }],
    width: "100%",
    aspectratio: "16:9",
    autostart: false,
    });
    jwplayer("video_image'.$iId.'").onError ( function(event) {
    setTimeout(function()
    {
    jwplayer("player").play(true);
    },2000);
    }
    );
    </script>';

} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

in JavaScript you can:

```
var myPlayers = $('.post_image div');
var numPlayers = myPlayers.length;
for (i=0;i<numPlayers;i++) {
    //this for loop will stop all the videos from playing
    jwplayer("'video_image'+i").stop();
}
//then you can play the video you want to play here
```

Sorry, my php is not great. Hopefully this will help you.

Comment: great but my question is i need only single video play at time and all other should be pause how can i do this.please see this link http://www.followmeapp.com/user/profile.php?type=%27v%27&uid=1686

Comment: i added some things that might make this a little clearer.